# Include link together delivery option in checkout - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, delivery

i want include a link with information in popup together to the delivery option in checkout.
When in Magento you are in checkout and you have choose delivery option (shipping methods), i want in one delivery option put a link with the text (more info this option) per example.
Where file is for include code?
Manu thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific file per method but the methods are outputted via the template file `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` which you could copy to your own template file and make the required changes in the foreach loop

Comment: Many thanks for you reply. You want say in app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/onepage?

Comment: Exactly, but the origional is in `base/default` or `rwd/default`

Comment: @TinoGoddiva did this solve your question?

Comment: So i think that yes, but not working. Not show nothing. I am trying directly in csv and show link in the method shipping but not open popup...